# Unity 2D - State Machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, state

I made a state machine to control my inputs and state animations. How can I use the following enum:

```
public enum mover_personagem
{
    mover_on,
    move_off
}
```

to activate and deactive input as follows:

```
private void Movimentar(float horizontal)
{
    if (move == mover_personagem.mover_on)
    {
        anim.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")));

        myRigibody2D.velocity = new Vector2(
            horizontal * moveSpeed,
            myRigibody2D.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

If i use the state `mover_off` when a dialog box is open for the player stop walk animation, it's not working.

Comment: if( mover_personagem == move.mover_on ) is wrong, you are compering enum type with enum value. You need to set the enum value in same variable and use it istead of mover_personagem == ...

Comment: Maybe you are no setting correct variable. I mean you edit some other enum "move" while the "move" in class with code above stays "mover_personagem.mover_on". Couse it should work.

Comment: If i instantiate on Movimentar class how public and instantiate on DialogueBox class how public, the enum does not become static ? What i need is change the current state on all class which was instantiated, with this i can control the states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Class named `Globals` or whatever you want where you can declare all the static variables.

For example, you have created your `enum` and its `variable` in `Globals.cs`.

```
public enum MOVER_STATE
{
    ON,
    OFF
}

public class Globals
{
    public static MOVER_STATE CURRENT_MOVER_STATE = MOVER_STATE.OFF; // Initial State
}
```

Now you can check it anywhere in any class, like

```
switch(Globals.CURRENT_MOVER_STATE){
    case MOVER_STATE.OFF:
        //TODO: Do anything if Off
        break;
    case MOVER_STATE.ON:
        //TODO: Do anything if On
        break;
    }
```

You can also assign it anywhere.